# Type '{ error: string; }' is not assignable to type 'string'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Данный код вызывает ошибку `Type '{ error: string; closeCallback: () => void; }' is not assignable to type 'string'`.

```
this.state.errorInfoForShow &&
   <StampErrorModal
       error={this.state.errorInfoForShow}
       closeCallback={this.closeErrorInfoModal}
   />
```

Хотя типы в функции прописаны верно

```
const StampErrorModal = (error: string | null, closeCallback: () => any) => {
 return(
     stampErrorModalTemplate(error, closeCallback)
 );
}
export default StampErrorModal;
```

Причём всё работает, если изменить

```
 <StampErrorModal
     error={this.state.errorInfoForShow}
     closeCallback={this.closeErrorInfoModal}
 />
```

на

```
StampErrorModal(this.state.errorInfoForShow, this.closeErrorInfoModal)
```

Но мне необходимо не трогать модуль, в котором вызывается код, а изменять только функцию StampErrorModal

Comment: в метод компонента должен передаваться **один** объект props, а ты передаешь два, при прямом вызове. В случае же с атрибутами, они собираются в один объект, с указанным типом. Поэтому и ошибка

Comment: Спасибо, теперь всё работает

Answer (score 0):

В функциональный реакт компонет пропсы попадают не как список аргументов, а как поля в объекте с пропсами, т.е. когда ты передаешь в компонент пропсы:

```
 <StampErrorModal
     error={this.state.errorInfoForShow}
     closeCallback={this.closeErrorInfoModal}
 />
```

то в функции StampErrorModal ты получишь один аргумент `props` (объект) с полями `error` и `closeCallback`

попробуй сделать так:

```
type Props = {
    error: string | null,
    closeCallback: () => any
}

const StampErrorModal = ({error, closeCallback}: Props ) => {
```